# Set typeface to listview items in android

Tags: android, listview, typeface

I need to add custom typeface for the listview items. And I have added the values to the list using using adapter like this

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), newList, R.layout.club_list2, from, to);
```

Here I want to set typeface for the textviews in club_list2 layout. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want set your custom typeface from xml you can do this

```
public class TypefaceTextView extends TextView {

    private static Map<String, Typeface> mTypefaces;

    public TypefaceTextView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TypefaceTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (mTypefaces == null) {
            mTypefaces = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
        }

        // prevent exception in Android Studio / ADT interface builder
        if (this.isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }

        final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, styleable.TypefaceTextView);
        if (array != null) {
            final String typefaceAssetPath = array.getString(
                    R.styleable.TypefaceTextView_customTypeface);

            if (typefaceAssetPath != null) {
                Typeface typeface = null;

                if (mTypefaces.containsKey(typefaceAssetPath)) {
                    typeface = mTypefaces.get(typefaceAssetPath);
                } else {
                    AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
                    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, typefaceAssetPath);
                    mTypefaces.put(typefaceAssetPath, typeface);
                }

                setTypeface(typeface);
            }
            array.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

in xml.

```
<com.example.TypefaceTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        geekui:customTypeface="fonts/yourfont.ttf" />
```

and your font should be in asset/fonts/ folder

create resource file inside values and set it as name attrs.xml

then copy past this there

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TypefaceTextView">
        <attr name="customTypeface" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Comment: I'm getting logcat error "TypefaceTextView cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: com.example.TypefaceTextView is an example path. make sure you set the right path i.e com.<your package name> ..

Comment: styleable.TypefaceTextView is showing me error and i have imported my project R.stylable

Comment: Try to do as most as you can in the xml layout files because inflating a layout is a lot faster then doing source code stuff. So this is a nice solution! Good job @fish40

Comment: Great accept as a best answer plz, that can help to others too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all to use the same one, use android:typeface in the xml.  If you want themto use different ones, set it on the TextView in your getView function.

Comment: how to add a custom typeface to xml?

Comment: If its custom it may be easier just to do it in code then, especially if loading from assets.  Do it in the getView of the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

the default is not Arial. The default is Droid Sans.

**change to a different built-in font**

Second, to change to a different built-in font, use android:typeface in layout XML or setTypeface() in Java(android).

**Example**

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/Arial.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
tv.setTypeface(tf)
```